# How to retrieve the count of the number of rows in asp.net mvc from sql database?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I am trying to print something if the number of rows returned is more than 0 based on a query:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString")){
  con.Open();
  string query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Some_Table WHERE Val > 5";
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // get the value of the count
  if (count > 0) 
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Returned more than 0 rows");
  }
  else
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Did not return more than 0 rows");
  }
  Console.ReadLine();
}
```

How can I find the number of rows returned?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capturing count from an SQL query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668911/capturing-count-from-an-sql-query)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to count the number of rows from sql table in c#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20160928/how-to-count-the-number-of-rows-from-sql-table-in-c)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your query always return one row even no rows exists. It will return 0 if no rows exists for your `WHERE` condition

Use [SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar Method ()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString"))
{
  con.Open();
  string query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Some_Table WHERE Val > 5";

  using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
  {
      int rowsAmount = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar(); // get the value of the count
      if (rowsAmount > 0) 
      {
          Console.WriteLine("Returned more than 0 rows");
      }
      else
      {
          Console.WriteLine("Did not return more than 0 rows");
      }

      Console.ReadLine();
}
```

`ScalarValue` will return first column of first row of query result. So for your query this is more effective method to retrieve information you need.

Comment: The database helper in WebMatrix is a far easier to read and work with than the overly verbose SqlCommand approach - much better for a newcomer as this guy seems to be.

Comment: @JamesHarcourt, I think it is opinion based. Instead for newcomer, I think, much better to get a picture how ADO.NET works.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this, Because [ExecuteNonQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx) - returns the number of rows affected.

```
int numberOfRecords = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
if (numberOfRecords  > 0) 
{
  Console.WriteLine("Returned more than 0 rows");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Did not return more than 0 rows");
}
```

Comment: Won't this return 1?

Comment: this not work for OP's query - `SELECT COUNT(*)` will always return 1 row

Comment: Thanks a lot @Sajeetharan.

Comment: However, I was having trouble using this.

Answer (score 1):

The ExecuteScalar() method of the SQLClient Command object is specifically provided for returning single values from a query.  It is more efficient in terms of code and performance.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString"))
{
conn.Open();
string query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Some_Table WHERE Val > 5";
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, con);
Int32 count = (Int32) cmd.ExecuteScalar()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `DataSet` to get the count

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
da.SelectCommand = cmd;
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

da.Fill(ds);

var count = ds.Tables[0].Rows.count;
```