# Displaying the number of rows in database in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I have a database with some info, and I need to display the number of rows to webpage. I tried getting the number according to [How to retrieve the count of the number of rows in asp.net mvc from sql database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40821106/how-to-retrieve-the-count-of-the-number-of-rows-in-asp-net-mvc-from-sql-database) :
code in Model:

```
   public int getNumber()
   {
       using(var con = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString")
       {
           con.Open();
           string query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM AspNetUsers"; // table name - AspNetUsers

           using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
           {
              return (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
           }
       }
   }
```

How do I display the number to the view? Creating object of the model class doesn't seem to work, since it need Ilogger. I now wonder whether I should put this code in a controller.

Comment: What makes you think it needs an ILogger? Am I correct in assuming this is ASP.NET MVC? Please tag your question with the appropriate framework.

Comment: @mason The constructor of the Model class requires ILogger<ModelName>. I have tried to create another blank constructor, but got error - there can only be one

Comment: I don't know why a model would need an ILogger....and I don't know what error you would get if you added an additional constructor: C# classes can have more than 1 model. When you run into issues, make sure you fully describe them. You haven't provided the code for the model class you're trying to work with, so when you say "doesn't seem to work" in your question, it's not clear at all what you've tried and specifically what isn't working about it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you drop in a button, and a text box to display the count?

Say, this markup:

```
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Rows in database = "></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Show table row count" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

And this code:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblHotelsA", conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                int? RowCount = (int?)cmdSQL.ExecuteScalar();
                TextBox1.Text = RowCount.ToString();
            }
        }
        
    }
```

And we get this:

[image]

Now, above is web forms, but the idea is really the same - you do a count(*) on that table - get the value and then shove it into a text box, or use in code, or do whatever you want.

Comment: Why use a nullable int? Won't the result always be a not-null int?

Comment: Sure, but if the table don't exist, then no value is returned - that line of code thus wouldn't compile if I used a non nullible int

Comment: If the table doesn't exist, an exception will be thrown, and thus no assignment would even happen. It wouldn't return a NULL value. So yes, this absolutely will compile with a non-nullable int. Since the RowCount variable can never be NULL in this code, it makes no sense to store it in a nullable int.

Comment: Not a huge deal in this case because it then gets converted to a string. But imagine for a moment that this was a properly encapsulated method that didn't mix UI and database concerns, and instead returned the value as a nullable int in a method. Now all downstream down has to deal with the nullable int even though it will never actually be null. More complicated code for no reason. In both that case and the code you've shown,  the only thing that really makes sense here is a non-nullable int.

Comment: If I was new to the language, like the asker presumably is here, I'd be very confused why someone is using a non-nullable int, and I might just conclude that somehow that could get a null value, when in reality there's absolutely no way that can happen. Let's set a good example in the code we write and not make changes that don't add any value and only add confusion.

Comment: Not a huge deal - a select command other then count(*) as noted can return null value. So while count(*) will return a int value? Use of ExecuteScaler does often return a null value. So, I am open to flipping a coin on this one either way.  Since Execute  scaler can OFTEN return a null value? Then it not all bad. So, in this case, no, it will not, but next time the poster uses Execute and gets a null - the posted code will be of help. Like everything, context matters. So to OP, you can use a int in place of int?. Just be aware that a non count sql query will often return a null value.

Comment: Context matters, yes. In this context, it's a SELECT COUNT being returned, which will never be NULL, so non-nullable int is the correct code. Will you please correct your answer, and then I'll remove these comments?

Comment: Right, but it ALSO rather common that ExecuteScaler CAN and WILL and OFTEN return a null value. If general use of ExecuteScaler could not, and in a rare day in hell could NEVER return a null, then you have a valid point. but, using that command means nulls often occur. We not limited to JUST using count() with ExecuteScalar - we are just not! Next time the poster uses ExecuteScaler, and it not a count(), then they need this information. This knowledge should be part of the skill set when using ExecuteScaler. Laughable that ExecuteScaler is limited to sql count(*) - beyond a laugh.

Comment: I never said we are limited to using count. However, the type you're casting to is directly tied to what the query returns. A SELECT COUNT should always be paired with an int, not a nullable int. If you change the query to return something else, then the type you cast and assign to should be based on the type of data the query results in.

Comment: that command often can, will and does return null, then my code reflects this reality. I quite much do that by habit. As I pointed out about the only exception here is when using count. In fact I even open to pointing out that command more often than not is not limited to using count (). If the more common use case was limited to count (), then I would even accept the narrative that the code posted is bad, or less then ideal. However, since it's common that command can return null, then it's not all bad of a pattern to adopt. Poster is free to use int but buyer beware.

Comment: And no you never suggested that command is limited to count (), but your current argument is based on using count (), and I'm not willing to limit this discussion to as such. The instant the user not using count () is quite much the same instant the poster will be adopting my code and how common+ often that command will require code as posted. Command is notorious for null values - my example helps more than it hurts.